# Implication and the equal sign?

Tags: calculus, logic

My question is best stated as an example:

$\int_{c_0}^{c_1} g(x)dx = G(c_1)-G(c_0)$, therefore

$\int_{c_0}^{c_1} g(x)dx \implies G(c_1)-G(c_0)$

From the two statements above, can we *always* conclude

$G({c_1})-G(c_0) \implies \int_{c_0}^{c_1} g({x})dx$?

If so, is this because mathematicians have been careful to define each operation to provide at most one output for each input? (in the example, the integration operation)

My suspicion is that the $=$ symbol is the same as $\iff$ symbol *precisely* because mathematicians have been careful to define each operation to provide at most one output for each input, but I am not sure if I am correct.

Comment: It makes *no* sense to put an implication there. Implication connects two propositions, and you have two *terms*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila do you mean here: $\int_{c_0}^{c_1} g(x)dx \implies G(c_1)-G(c_0)$?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are talking about. The equality sign is, in fact, an equivalence relation on the set $V\times V$ for an arbitrary set $V$. The sign $\Rightarrow$ (and $\Leftrightarrow$) is an operation $\{true,false\}^2\to\{true,false\}$.

Comment: Ovi, that is correct. This is not a well-formed mathematical statement (unless you are using $\implies$ in a non-standard way).

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Hm I'm sorry I haven't taken a logic class so I am not completely clear on the formal definitions of all the symbols

Comment: @Ovi you don't need a logic class for that, just the general idea how the mathematical notation works and how the proofs are written.

Comment: The second "statement", after the "therefore", isn't a statement at all. The integral is a term denoting a real number, and the difference of the values of $G$ is another term denoting a real number; numbers are not propositions, you can't combine them with logical connectives such as $\Rightarrow$ — it's gibberish.

Comment: @BrianO Doesn't it make sense to read it as "If we apply the operation $\int_{c_0}^{c_1}$ (sorry if this is not actually a formally valid operation, I am just using it for example) to $g(x)$, it implies we are computing $G(c_1)-G(c_0)$"?

Comment: The notation somewhat parallels English. Compare the statements: "the specimen is an insect, therefore it is an animal" vs. "an elephant therefore bananas". One makes sense while the other is blabber. A logical connective such as $\implies$ *connects* two complete thoughts, so-to-speak.

Comment: @Brody Please see my comment above

Comment: Ah I see what you want to say. It's still equality you'd want to use, not logical equivalence. For example, if for two functions $f,g$ we have $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$, then we can conclude $f=g$. In your example, we know that the first statement is true for all $(c_0, c_1)$. Unfortunately, in this case there's no common notation for discarding the arguments $(c_0, c_1)$. What you mean, though, is: the function $(c_0,c_1)\mapsto\int_{c_0}^{c_1}g(x)dx = $ the function $(c_0,c_1)\mapsto G(c_1) - G(c_0)$. Perhaps you could write: $\int_{\bullet}^{\star}g = G(\star)-G(\bullet)$.

Comment: @Ovi Your idea is totally understandable, but it unfortunately doesn't line up with mathematical convention. You're adding more to the expression than it's really saying. Informally speaking, $$\int_{c_0}^{c_1} g(x)\,\text{d}x$$ simply says "the definite integral of $g(x)$ with respect to $x$ from $c_0$ to $c_1$". It's essentially just an object, again so-to-speak, and not a complete thought. This may simply be a nuance of mathematical language, which is formalized in logic.

Comment: (cont ... Perhaps you could write: $\int_{\bullet}^{\star}g = G(\star)-G(\bullet)$.) It *is* a convention that using a non-variable-name symbol within a term means we're talking about the function that arises by abstracting/binding a variable in that position.

Comment: @BrianO Exactly, I mean "the function $a$ when applied to $(c_0, c_1)$ produces the result $\int_{c_0}^{c_1} g(x) dx$ . The function $b$ when applied to $(c_0, c_1)$ produces the result $G(c_1)-G(c_0)$. Since $\int_{c_0}^{c_1} g(x) dx$ and $G(c_1)-G(c_0)$ are the same object/have the same value, does it necessarily imply that the function $a$ is the same function as $b$? If so, is this purely a consequence of mathematicians being careful enough to define functions as having at most one output for each input? Is the definition of functions as having at most one output for each input...

Comment: @BrianO ...input sufficient and necessary for determining $a$ and $b$ must be the same operation?

Comment: @Ovi, yes, basically by extensionality. Two sets are equal iff they have the same members, thus two functions (their 'graphs', anyway) are equal iff they have the same set of "inputs" (same domain) and they give the same "output" (give the same value) on each "input".

Answer (score 1):

The equality sign means "the things on both sides of this are equal".

$A \implies B$ means "if A, then B" or "it can't be true that A is true but B isn't".

It makes no sense to have something that evaluates to a number on either side of an implication; implications work with *propositions*, statements that can be true or false.